# Does Zhang's work imply that the next greatest prime number is necessarily less than $2^{57,885,161}-1+ 70000000$?

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes, prime-gaps

Actually the greatest known prime is $2^{57,885,161}-1$. Zhang's work proved that the interval between pairs of prime numbers is limited to $70,000,000$. Does it imply that the next greatest prime number is necessarily less than $2^{57,885,161}-1 + 70000000$?

Comment: Not at all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime

Comment: Actually, the prime number theorem implies that the average gap between primes will increase. Zhang's work just proves that no matter how far out you go, you can still find prints somewhere that are close together.

Comment: That's a good question. It is based on a misunderstanding, but it is a more sophisticated one than usual.

Comment: You've misread Zhang's result. There can be arbitrarily large gaps in primes - indeed, it is know that there are - there's just infinitely cases where $p_{n+1}-p_n<70,000,000$.

Answer (score 2):

No, it implies that there are always prime numbers that are separated by 70,000,000 after any given prime that you specify. There may not be another pair of primes with a separation of 70,000,000 until after the number $10^{10^{100}}$, who knows, but there certainly exists an infinite number of pairs of primes after $10^{10^{100}}$ with a difference of less than 70,000,000.

Comment: Good answer. But it could be misleading to stress the "who knows" as actually I think one does, or at least could know; that those gaps are not rare.

Comment: I got it, thanks.